# What kind of formula is Location.distanceTo() using?

Tags: android

What kind of formula is the `Location.distanceTo()` method using?

Is it the Haversine formula ?

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/location/Location.java#Location.distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source of the [android.location.Location](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/location/Location.java/?v=source) class, you can see the following comment:

```
private static void computeDistanceAndBearing(double lat1, double lon1,
    double lat2, double lon2, float[] results) {
    // Based on http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PUBS_LIB/inverse.pdf
    // using the "Inverse Formula" (section 4)
    ...
```

They are using the inverse solution of geodesics, found in section four of [this article](http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PUBS_LIB/inverse.pdf).  This is different from the haversine formula, which has been known to be less accurate ([but also a little faster](http://jsperf.com/vincenty-vs-haversine-distance-calculations)).